# Recover id in display list using combobox

Tags: c#, ajax, combobox

i need to recover the id of element selected in combobox in dev express
and this is the code of combobox:

```
 @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "comboBox4";
    settings.Width = 180;
    settings.SelectedIndex = 0;
    settings.Properties.DropDownWidth = 550;
    settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Editors", Action = "MultiColumnComboBoxPartial" };
    settings.Properties.CallbackPageSize = 30;
    settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;
    settings.Properties.TextFormatString = "{1}";
    settings.Properties.ValueField = "Id";
    settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string);
   settings.Properties.Columns.Add("Id", "Id", 130).SetColVisible(false);
  // settings.Properties.Columns.Add("Id", "Id", 130).SetColVisibleIndex(1);

    settings.Properties.Columns.Add("Nom", "Nom", 130);
    settings.Properties.Columns.Add("Prenom", "Prenom", Unit.Percentage(100));
    settings.Properties.Columns.Add("DateNaissance", "DateNaissance", 60);
    settings.Properties.Columns.Add("CodeClient", "CodeClient", 100);



}
     ).BindList(client).GetHtml()
```

and this the method ajax how i put the value of any custom with ajax:

```
function Addprojet() {
        debugger;
        var nom = $("#nom2_I").val();
        var description = $("#Description_I").val();
        var client = $("#comboBox4_I").val();
        var chef = $("#chefid_I").val();
        var complexite = $("#comboBox1_I").val();
        var taille = $("#comboBox2_I").val();

        var datedebut = $("#datedebut_I").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Projet/AjouterProjet?nom=" + nom + "&description=" + description + "&client=" + client + "&chef=" + chef + "&complexite=" + complexite + "&taille=" + taille + "&datedebut=" + datedebut,   //          /Controlleur/Action
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'text',
            //data : {Nom: nom},
            success: function (responseText) {
                debugger;
                if (responseText == "True") {
                    location.replace("/Client/listeclients");
                }
                else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

how can i resolve this issue because i need to recover the id of client without displaying in the list in the combobox 
can semeone help me to fix it .

Comment: Perhaps "DevExpress" and maybe "Razor" could be added as tags to this question.

Comment: I have methods in a Controller, but I don't think we're talking about the same thing.